# TypeScript type guards and "only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."

Tags: typescript

I'm using Typescript 3.2.2 and unable to achieve the most basic implementation of type guards:

```
interface Bird {
    fly(): boolean;
}

interface Fish {
    swim(): boolean;
}

function swimIfYouCan(x: Fish | Bird) {
    if ((<Fish>x).swim) {
        return true
    }
}
```

This produces `Error:(50, 11) TS2693: 'Fish' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.` in WebStorm and `SyntaxError: /Users/sea-kent/git/docket-management/webapp/src/App.tsx: Unexpected token (51:8)` from `yarn`. Is there a configuration needed to enable this syntax?

Comment: If you're using TSX, `<Fish>` could be an element - use `x as Fish` instead. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54614279/3001761, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe that was it thank you

Comment: Related: [Why does 'instanceof' in TypeScript give me the error “'Foo' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46703364/why-does-instanceof-in-typescript-give-me-the-error-foo-only-refers-to-a-ty)

Answer (score 2):

There are three different approaches possible that come to my mind for your problem.

1. If you want to cast it and directly use it you have to use the `as` operator (as mentioned by @jonrsharpe in the comments), so for example `(x as Fish).swim`
2. use the `in` operator to check if it is available, e.g. `if ('swim' in x)`
3. Last but not least (and for this case in my opinion the best case), simply do an instance of check to check what instance you've got: `if (x instance of Fish)`

Edit: Didn't read the question well enough, you can't check for interfaces in runtime. But there is no harm in creating a class on top of the interface

Comment: The last will not work, since interfaces don't exist in runtime.

Comment: `x instanceof Fish` gives the same problem `'Fish' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Comment: `in` works fine if I just want to call the method, but if I want to have a `Fish` to pass to something else that is checking, it won't do. I think `x as Fish` is the winner. Thanks.

Comment: yeah didn't read question proper enough that he is using an interface and not a class

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to do pattern matching by checking the existence of a property is the `in` operator:

```
interface Bird {
    fly(): boolean;
}

interface Fish {
    swim(): boolean;
}

function move(x: Fish | Bird) {
  if ("swim" in x) {
    return x.swim();
  } else {
    return x.fly();
  }
}
```

By using the `in` operator you can avoid the assertion.

Comment: Thanks. That works for this trivial case, but if I want to go a step further and actually have a `Fish` to pass to something else, I think `x as Fish` is more inline with the goal: ```function isFish(x: Fish | Bird): x is Fish {
    return (x as Fish).swim !== undefined;
}```