# can i use the tsx extension for test files if using react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, jestjs

I have a react application in react redux with typescript. I am using jest for writing tests. I am confused about what should be the extension of test files according to convention. whether js/ts or tsx.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

> Can I use the `tsx` extension for test files if using React with TypeScript?

**Yes**. You can use the `*.tsx` extension for test files if using React with TypeScript.

> Any leads would be appreciated.

There are multiple ways to setup `jest` with TypeScript. For one example [try running this script](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-typescript) from a terminal:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --typescript
cd my-app
npm run eject
```

That will generate a project that is configured to run tests with the `*.tsx` extension. You can see its `jest` configuration inside the `src/package.json` file and an example test inside the `src/App.test.tsx` file. The latter looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use .test.tsx extension **if a test file contains embedded xml-like JSX code** (but not because you are testing component).

According to [Is there any downside to using .tsx instead of .ts all the times in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224007/is-there-any-downside-to-using-tsx-instead-of-ts-all-the-times-in-typescript)

> with the .tsx files you could use the all JSX (JavaScript XML) code.
> In the .ts file you can only use just typescript.

If you have test written in pure Typescript, .test.tsx is a wrong extension.

Extensions are used to describe type of content in the file.
If it is a test file written in typescript, it should be .test.ts,  if it is written in javascript, it should be .test.js.

> The extension indicates a characteristic of the file contents or its
> intended use.
> From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension

If you try to use .test.ts extension with test files that include jsx/html elements declarations, it can cause errors as described in ["Navbar refers to a value, but is being used as a type here" when trying to render a shallow copy of my component when testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58341545/navbar-refers-to-a-value-but-is-being-used-as-a-type-here-when-trying-to-rend). For such files using .test.tsx is appropriate.

Note that for JavaScript .test.js extension is good for any type of tests, with or without Jsx elements

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing JSX(e.g components) you should use the .tsx extension
If you're not testing JSX(e.g reducers) you should use .ts

You should also have a jest.config.js file, find the key "moduleFileExtensions" to se all available file extensions that jest accepts

Comment: You should use .ts/.js extension for test files written in typescript/JavaScript. To specify what you are testing you should use first part of the file name, e.g. myComponent.test.ts