# What is the difference between .ts and .tsx extensions. Both are used as extensions for typescript files in react. So where should we use them?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to react and I am working on a project. I come across both `.ts` and `.tsx` extensions. I don't understand where should I use `.ts` and `.tsx`. Any help on this is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224007/is-there-any-downside-to-using-tsx-instead-of-ts-all-the-times-in-typescript

Comment: Roughly I use .ts files for plain scripts and .tsx for files containg markup

Comment: same as difference between c and c++ :p

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any downside to using .tsx instead of .ts all the times in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224007/is-there-any-downside-to-using-tsx-instead-of-ts-all-the-times-in-typescript)

Answer (score 409, accepted):

Use `.ts` for pure TypeScript files.

Use `.tsx` for files which contain JSX.

For example, a React component would be `.tsx`, but a file containing helper functions would be `.ts`.

Comment: To add to this (correct) answer, it's the same as if you were doing React without TypeScript, you would use .js and .jsx for pure javascript vs JSX javascript files.

Comment: not necessarily, you can write pure TS React components, I'd reword it as: a react component containing "tag like" react syntax (which is really tsx). Just to clarify that to anyone that doesn't really know about it.

Comment: I spent many hours figuring out why my .ts files keep throwing errors for things like `return <div>hello!</div>;`. Kill me please.

Comment: what about hook files that doesnt contain react component?  like maybe a react spring custom hooks is it useAnimation.ts or useAnimation.tsx?

Answer (score 59):

.tsx extension is used when we want to embed JSX elements inside the files while .ts is used for plain Typescript files and do not support adding JSX Elements.

Answer (score 33):

All of the above answers are correct.

> .ts files contains only pure TypeScript

> .tsx have included JSX also.

On another point of view, you can copy everything from a `.ts` file and paste on `.tsx` file, and you don't need to modify anything. But if you're copying from a `.tsx` file you need to refactor it by removing the `JSX` elements.

Comment: Hint: If you use <> to do type-casting in your .ts file and you paste that into a .tsx file, then that will lead to errors. Replace all <typeA> myVar with myVar as typeA and you're good to go.

Comment: @MarcMiller Good clarification you gave about being able to put the contexts of a .ts file into a .tsx file without issue. That leaves me to wonder if it's terribly wrong to just go ahead and name all files in a React project with .tsx?

Answer (score 8):

when you use .tsx you can use JSX in that particular file while .ts gives you error.

Answer (score 8):

A .ts file is pure typescript while .tsx is an extended syntax format of typescript which combines both typescript and HTML in the same file. For example:

```
const element = <h1>Hello, world!</h1>;
```

This is beneficial because we can start to define the output within the code directly and makes it easier to incorporate data, making the HTML similar to templates:

```
const name = 'Josh Perez';
const element = <h1>Hello, {name}</h1>; // Outputs <h1>Hello, Josh Perez</h1>
```

https://react.dev/learn#writing-markup-with-jsx
https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Answer (score 3):

`.ts` is used for pure TypeScript files and `.tsx` is used for files with JSX.

Answer (score 0):

.tsx contains jsx and .ts is a pure typescript file. very useful in React TS if you want to create custom hooks and interfaces that will be used in many files.