# Rendering based on Enum in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

In App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { IconType }, Icon from "./icons"; //<-this line gives syntax error

export default function App() {
    return <Icon icon=IconType.Complete/>
};
```

In icon.js

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';

export enum IconType //<-this line gives syntax error
{
     Complete,
     Active,
     Risk,
     Overdue
}
const Icon = ({ props }) => {
     if (props.icon === IconType.Complete){
       return <h1>icon</h1>
     }
}

export default Icon;
```

See [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-help-ihpk1j)

How should I fixed the syntax error above marked in the comment?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error and you can observe from the description `'enum' declarations can only be used in TypeScript files`.

From the documentation.

> Enums are one of the few features TypeScript has which is not a type-level extension of JavaScript.

[Read this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#:%7E:text=Enums%20are%20one%20of%20the,numeric%20and%20string%2Dbased%20enums.) for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

`Enum` is a feature used in `typescript` and it can not be used in `.js` files.

So, the first way is to install `typescript` and rename the `.js` to `.tsx`. The file extension of `.tsx` let you can write `typescript` and [jsx](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html). For more explanation please reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56871384/what-is-the-difference-between-ts-and-tsx-extensions-both-are-used-as-extensi).

I have been improved on this changes and this is a workable example [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-help-forked-p8ytss?file=/src/icon.tsx).